# How to disable horizontal scrolling in org.eclipse.epf.richtext.RichTextEditor

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp, rich-text-editor

I have an Eclipse RCP application that has a widget that uses the rich text editor from `org.eclipse.epf.richtext.RichTextEditor`. So all the code is open to me to alter to how I see fit. I have found that the rte uses a browser to display the text.

My problem is that I want the rte to wrap the text and not put a horizontal scroll bar. So I was hoping to see if anyone has used this rte and figured out how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I think that in every SWT widget's constructor you can pass a style. So for example if you want vertical scroll but no horizontal you can do this:

```
new MyWidget(parent, SWT.V_SCROLL);
```

This way the widget won't scroll horizontally. the `RichTextEditor` itself does not have anything about text wrapping in its API so I guess that you can't alter that directly.

A little more about SWT styles: [SWT style bits](http://wiki.eclipse.org/SWT_Widget_Style_Bits)

Comment: I tried all sorts of combinations of styles, WRAP, V_SCROLL, NO_SCROLL, and nothing seems to have any effect. Thanks for the idea though.

Comment: Did you check the official documentation?

Comment: I have been unable to find any documentation. It took me a while to figure out how to even use the rich text editor because there were no instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Examine the HTML which is displayed in the [SWT browser widget](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/snippets/#browser) (call `getText()`). That should give you an idea how it's organized. Find the HTML element which wraps the editor, set it's width to `100%` and make sure you do the same for the `body` and `html` elements to have the widget's width propagate to the editor element.

That should already fix the issue unless the text in the editor contains elements which are wider than the widget.

Comment: That seems like a pretty good approach, however I am not exactly sure how to do it. I think that the browser widget lets you execute javascript which maybe you cam set the width that way but I do not know javascript so I am unsure.

Comment: There is a snippet which shows how to manipulate the DOM. Just click on the link in my answer.

Comment: so how do you tell it to set the width in javascript?

Comment: Please google for an answer and ask a new question if you can't get it to work.

Comment: Since I have never used javascript and have little html experience I I'm going to probably ask real dumb questions. So would I somehow find some script that uses the document.write() and add in html tags to set the width attribute? is that what you are suggesting I do?

Comment: I am really not sure how to set the html width without using css. just to reiterate, I have little to no experience web programming